# how do or what is the best way to generate AES key using openssl programmatically?

Tags: c++, c

how do or what is the best way to generate AES key using openssl programmatically? Saw recommendations using RAND_bytes. I also come across this API — AES_set_encrypt_key(....). But the first parameter seems to be user’s encrypted key. So, I think you I need to generate an AES key first b4 calling this API.
Please advise

Comment: _"...best way..."_ - it depends: how will the key be stored, transmitted, used externally, remembered by a human?

Comment: This will be stored in the database. I just want to know what is the practice for this case